# How to enable v35 hinting engine in libfreetype 2.9.1?

Tags: package-management, fonts, 18.10

I tried

> FREETYPE_PROPERTIES="truetype:interpreter-version=35
>   cff:no-stem-darkening=1 autofitter:warping=1"

In command line for Chrome, Firefox, gnome-terminal, Nautilus, Telegram, Skype.
Tried this properties in etc/environment and export command in freetype.sh.

Tried to compile this library myself and replace corresponding .so file at usr/lib...

None of those solutions worked.
I have vm with 16.04 to compare fonts rendering with current 18.10 distro.

Are there any workarounds to enable v35 hinting engine?

**P.S.** I noticed that there are some other libfreetype.so.6.12.1 libs in snap core (Ubuntu core snap) and GNOME's dirs. But those libs should determine FREETYPE_PROPERTIES too.